# Como fazer upload de várias imagens para SQL Server usando JSON no ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, json

Preciso inserir um conjunto de informações nos dados SQL Server banco de dados, mas junto com eles algumas fotos junto com algumas cordas. Estou querendo mover tudo por JSON.

Entrada para selecionar a imagem:

```
  <th> 
      <div  class = "form-group" > 
           <label  for = "legendaFoto5" > Legenda </label> 
           <input  type = "text"  class = "form-control"  id = "legendaFoto5"  placeholder = "Legenda da Foto " > 
      </ div> 
  </ th>
```

Como passo para JSON (não está indo bem até que eu mudei o primeiro `sfoto1InputFile` para ser capaz de carregar, mas não deu certo):

```
<script  type = "text/javascript" > 
    $ ( document ). ready ( function  ()  { 
        $ ( "#salvarLevantamentoFicha" ). click ( function  ( evt )  { 
            var sfoto1InputFile = $ ( "#foto1InputFile" ). get ( 0 ). files [ 0 ]; 
            var sfoto2InputFile = $ ( "#foto2InputFile" ). image ; 
            var sfoto3InputFile = $ ( "#foto3InputFile" ). image ; 
            var sfoto4InputFile = $ ( "#foto4InputFile" ). image ; 
            var sfoto5InputFile = $ ( "#foto5InputFile" ). image ;

            var strlegendaFoto1 = $ ( "#legendaFoto1" ). val (); 
            var strlegendaFoto2 = $ ( "#legendaFoto2" ). val (); 
            var strlegendaFoto3 = $ ( "#legendaFoto3" ). val (); 
            var strlegendaFoto4 = $ ( "#legendaFoto4" ). val (); 
            var strlegendaFoto5 = $ ( "#legendaFoto5" ). val (); 
          $ . getJSON ( "@Url.Content(" ~ /CadLevantamentoAmbiental/ SalvarFichaLevantamentoTC ")" ,  { 
                _sfoto1InputFile : sfoto1InputFile , 
                _sfoto2InputFile : sfoto2InputFile , 
                _sfoto3InputFile : sfoto3InputFile , 
                _sfoto4InputFile : sfoto4InputFile , 
                _sfoto5InputFile : sfoto5InputFile , 
                _strlegendaFoto1 : strlegendaFoto1 , 
                _strlegendaFoto2 : strlegendaFoto2 , 
                _strlegendaFoto3 : strlegendaFoto3 , 
                _strlegendaFoto4 : strlegendaFoto4 , 
                _strlegendaFoto5 : strlegendaFoto5                
             });

        }); 
    }); 
</ script>
```

Comment: Acho que aqueles espaços na `@Url.Content` não são legais...

Comment: Nunca tentei fazer essa funcionalidade, mas [sei que o Uploadfy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uploadfy/) permite isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu usaria o plugin [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

[Exemplo de como utilizá-lo](http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery) com ASP.NET MVC.

Agora, corrigindo seu exemplo, acredito que uma troca de `$.getJSON` por `$.post()`; passando os devidos parâmetros.